# Cloud computing service to run thousands of containers in parallel

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, devops

Is there any provider, that offers such an option out of the box? I need to run at least 1K concurrent sessions (docker containers) of headless web-browsers (firefox) for complex UI tests. I have a Docker image that I just want to deploy and scale to 1000 1CPU/1GB instances in second, w/o spending time on maintaining the cluster of servers (I need to shut them all down after the job is done), just focuse on the code. The most close thing I found so far is Amazon ECS/Fargate, but their limits have no sense to me ("Run containerized applications in production" -> max limit: 50 tasks -> production -> ok). Am I missing something?

Comment: Amazon's initial limits can be raised dramatically. They just make you ask support for it because they don't want to have to refund $20k to someone who made a mistake and fired up thousands of servers accidentally while learning the system.

Comment: ok, thanks for info, I have not tried yet asking the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html) might be a better solution for your use case. You define a "compute environment" that provides a certain level of capacity, then submit tasks that are run on that compute environment.

I don't think that you'll find anything that can start up an environment and deploy a large number of tasks in "one second": in my experience it takes about a minute or two ramp-up time for Batch, although once the machines are up and running they are able to sequence jobs quickly. You should also give consideration to whether it makes sense to run all 1,000 jobs concurrently; that will depend on what you're trying to get out of your tests.

You'll also need to be aware of any places where you might be throttled (for example, retrieving configuration from the AWS Parameter Store). [This talk](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/how-aqr-capital-uses-aws-to-research-new-investment-signals) from last year's NY Summit covers some of the issues that the speaker ran into when deploying multiple-thousands of concurrent tasks.

Comment: I've checked the AWS Batch docs, but it's still not clear to me - if it possible to run firefox there (inside the Docker container ofc)? and could you clarify the actual limits on the number of containers I can run there at the same time? here I can find the max queue size of jobs, but how they will be processed?(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/service_limits.html) one by one?

Comment: Batch is just a mechanism for scheduling Docker containers. If you've created a Docker container to run Firefox, then it can run in Batch.

Comment: Regarding maximum number of containers, that will depend on available compute resources available to your account: you can specify a managed environment with 2048 vCPUs, and I would expect that AWS will assign whatever instance types are appropriate to fulfill that. However, I can't say for sure as I've only used much smaller clusters.

Comment: seems that my Batch limit will be based on my EC2 limit (20 instances per region)

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda layers to run headless browsers (I know there are several implementations for chromium/selenium on github, not sure about firefox).

Alternatively you could try and contact the AWS team to see how much the limit for concurrent tasks on Fargate can be increased. As you can [see at the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_limits.html), the 50 task is a soft limit and can be raised.

Be aware if you start via Fargate, there is some API limit on the requests per second. You need to make sure you [throttle your API calls](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/9uhhfw/can_someone_help_me_understand_the_fargate_limits/) or you use the [ECS Create Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/basic-service-params.html).

In any case, starting 1000 tasks would require 1000 seconds, which is probably not what you expect.

Those limits are not there if you use ECS, but in that case you need to manage the cluster, so it might be a good idea to explore the lambda option.

Comment: there is no way to run firefox w/ lambda as far as I know

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have seen Chromium on lambda, but I don't recall seeing Firefox, so you might be right there is some kind of incompatibility, or maybe it is a matter of expending some time integrating. I haven't looked at that in detail. A potential workaround would be exploring the possibility of using Chromium rather than Firefox (if acceptable)

Comment: Note that ECS allows you to launch up to 10 tasks with a single RunTask API call so it would not necessarily require 1000 RunTask API calls and 1000 seconds to launch those tasks